# TableViewCells are getting overlapped after search in titanium

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, titanium

I am having label on `tableViewCell` instead of title property. And I am performing search by taking value from `searchBar` and after 4 letters in searchBar search method is called in which rows are getting refreshed with new datasource. And datasource is getting changed but cells are getting overlapped and consequently I am getting overlapped text. And I am getting error in **IOS 7.0 SDK** only. Any suggestions?

I have tried setting `tableView.data` null.

And also filterAtrribute property to be null. And as I am not defing `filterAttributeProperty` then `searchTableView` is getting no results until there is text in `searchBarField.

And if I am emptying `searchBarField` then tableView is not responding.

Comment: please share your code from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Its in titanium.. not in IOS.. target is IOS 7.0

Answer (score -1):

This has something to do with the reusing of table cells. Do you have any options to reuse them or not?